# dynamic_cast is failing when casting from base to child class

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I have a struct

```
struct foo : public std::map<std::string, int>
{
};
```

and a child struct;

```
struct bar : public foo
{
    int another_member;
}
```

But I can't use `bar* b = dynamic_cast<bar*>(f)` where f is a pointer to a foo.

Even if I refactor `foo` to

```
struct foo
{
     std::map<std::string, int> m;
};
```

I still have the problem. I've played around with my RTTI settings to no avail. What on earth is going on?

The error is:

> error C2683: 'dynamic_cast' : 'Credit::WaterfallSimulationResult' is
>   not a polymorphic type

Comment: Does `foo` have any `virtual` members?

Comment: I never understand the errors.

Comment: @SlodgeMonster how it prevents you from inserting them into the question?

Comment: @SlodgeMonster: you're joking, right? because **you** don't understand the error doesn't mean it's not helpful for someone who tries to help you!

Comment: `struct foo : public std::map<std::string, int>` its probably a bed idea. See declaration of std::map destructor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`dynamic_cast` will only work on polymorphic types, that is `struct`s or `class`es that have a virtual function table.

The best thing to do is to introduce a virtual function into your base `struct`, and the best function to introduce is the virtual destructor, which is arguably a good thing to do anyway:

```
struct foo
{
     std::map<std::string, int> m;
     virtual ~foo(){};
};
```

Note that this forces you to use your "refactored" form of `foo`: STL containers are not designed to be used as base classes.